# SOQL Salesforce database query, search for two joined fields with one string

Tags: search, salesforce

So far I'm generating a query like so:

`$query = "SELECT $imploded From Contact WHERE FirstName LIKE '%$var%' OR LastName LIKE '%$var%' OR Email LIKE '$var'";`

Where `imploded` contains a list of fields and `var` is the input from the search. Because of the way it's set up in the salesforce database, First name and last name are two different fields. So let's say the search is `Shelby`, you would get a response if Shelby is indeed in the database, however if you try `Shelby X`, it can't look into both fields and confirm this. Is there a way to make it search both First and Last names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Name` field is a read-only standard field that acts as a combination of `FirstName` and `LastName`. You should be able to use it in your query in a similar way:

```
$query = "SELECT $imploded From Contact WHERE
    FirstName LIKE '%$var%' OR LastName LIKE '%$var%'
    OR Name LIKE '%$var%' OR Email LIKE '%$var%'";
```

You may also want to look into [SOSL](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_sosl.htm), which allows you to search multiple fields across objects (or specify those that you are interested in).

Comment: I agree with JCD's solution and would also recommend looking into SOSL. As it happens name and email fields are included in the search. Here is an example of what that search would look like: List<List<SObject>> searchList = [FIND '*var*' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Contact (Id, Name, Email)];

Comment: And here is the link to the documentation: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_SOQL.htm